# Ajax to fire on page load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm hoping someone can find what my issue is. my script only fires when scrolled down... I need that functionality. What it doesn't do is fire on page load too which I need it to do initially. So it loads the content first, then I can scroll down the page for more new content.

I tried putting the ajax inside a function with the function name outside and it still didn't fire.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            flag = true;
            first = $('#first').val();
            limit = $('#limit').val();
            no_data = true;
            if (flag && no_data) {
                flag = false;
                $('#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "commentedoncontent.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        start: first,
                        limit: limit
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        flag = true;
                        $('#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        if (data.count > 0) {
                            first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                            limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());
                            $('#first').val(first + limit);
                            $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
                                //post content here
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('No more data to show');
                            no_data = false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        flag = true;
                        no_data = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The part inside of `ready` just attaches a scroll listener. What part do you want to run on load?

Comment: I would like the ajax to fire on page load (When page has refreshed) so I can see the new content..But also I want the scroll function to play its part in getting new content. It's not throwing any errors as its not firing on page load. Only when I scroll.

Comment: You're never telling it to fire on page load though. All you're doing on page load is attaching a scroll listener, which doesn't do anything until they scroll. See the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate it as a function, so you can call it on scroll AND on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            myFunction();
        }
    });
});
function myFunction(){
    /* all the logic goes here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help @LordNeo

Answer (score 1):

You can place your code in a function and then execute it on page load and on on scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doStuff(); //choose the name that you want 

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    doStuff();
   });
});

function doStuff(){    
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            flag = true;
            first = $('#first').val();
            limit = $('#limit').val();
            no_data = true;
            if (flag && no_data) {
                flag = false;
                $('#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "commentedoncontent.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        start: first,
                        limit: limit
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        flag = true;
                        $('#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        if (data.count > 0) {
                            first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                            limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());
                            $('#first').val(first + limit);
                            $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
                                //post content here
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('No more data to show');
                            no_data = false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        flag = true;
                        no_data = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

}
```